# Huge difference between ipa size and project size

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, ipa

I have a project with 5.2 Mb size. But when I create ipa file its size increases and becomes 71.2 Mb. Why does this happen? Is there any way to reduce it? I used swift 3 while developing this project.

Comment: I followed suggestions of Jim. File size is almost 40-50 Mb now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in Xcode 8.3 that causes large IPA file sizes.  Upgrade to 8.3.1, this has a fix for that bug in it.

Also, bear in mind that the Swift runtime libraries are copied into your application bundle.

Comment: Swift runtime libraries are about 30 mb, you won't be able to get rid of those.